# Unable to install hdf5 library from homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew, hdf5

I am trying to install the hdf5 library from Homebrew. Running `brew install hdf5` in the terminal returns the following error message:

> ==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
> Error: No similarly named formulae found.
> Error: No available formula or cask with the name "hdf5".
> ==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
> Error: No previously deleted formula found.
> ==> Searching taps on GitHub...
> Error: No formulae found in taps.

I am running this on a mac with Mojave version 10.14.6. What next steps should I try to download the hdf5 library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that at least part of my Homebrew download was in the wrong location.  Running `brew doctor`, I got `Warning: Homebrew/homebrew-core was not tapped properly!`. This was fixed by running `rm -rf "/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core"` and then `brew tap homebrew/core`.